# XCode 3.x to 4.0 upgrade issue

Tags: xcode4

I have just upgraded XCode 3.x to 4.0 and ran into following build error.

```
Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1
```

I tried juggling around this error but couldn't get rid of it. Does anyone know fix for this please?

Complete error message:

> Ld
>   /Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myApp-ddoknnyqnanytlcpbqpazmjjqbpx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/myApp.app/myApp
>   normal armv7 cd "/xcode -
>   svn/TheAppStudio/TheAppStudio" setenv
>   IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 4.2 setenv
>   PATH
>   "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2
>   -arch armv7 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk
>   -L/Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myApp-ddoknnyqnanytlcpbqpazmjjqbpx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos
>   -F/Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myApp-ddoknnyqnanytlcpbqpazmjjqbpx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos
>   -filelist /Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myApp-ddoknnyqnanytlcpbqpazmjjqbpx/Build/Intermediates/myApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/myApp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/myApp.LinkFileList
>   -dead_strip -all_load -ObjC -miphoneos-version-min=4.2 -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework
>   CoreGraphics -framework QuartzCore
>   /Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myApp-ddoknnyqnanytlcpbqpazmjjqbpx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libThree20.a
>   /Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myApp-ddoknnyqnanytlcpbqpazmjjqbpx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libThree20Core.a
>   /Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myApp-ddoknnyqnanytlcpbqpazmjjqbpx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libThree20Network.a
>   /Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myApp-ddoknnyqnanytlcpbqpazmjjqbpx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libThree20Style.a
>   /Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myApp-ddoknnyqnanytlcpbqpazmjjqbpx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libThree20UI.a
>   /Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myApp-ddoknnyqnanytlcpbqpazmjjqbpx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libThree20UICommon.a
>   /Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myApp-ddoknnyqnanytlcpbqpazmjjqbpx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libThree20UINavigator.a
>   -framework Security -framework SystemConfiguration -framework
>   MessageUI -framework AVFoundation
>   -framework MediaPlayer -framework CoreLocation -framework CoreLocation
>   -framework MapKit -framework CFNetwork -framework AudioToolbox -lz.1.2.3 -framework MobileCoreServices -lxml2 -o /Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myApp-ddoknnyqnanytlcpbqpazmjjqbpx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/myApp.app/myApp
>
> arm-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1:
>   /Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myApp-ddoknnyqnanytlcpbqpazmjjqbpx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libThree20.a:
>   No such file or directory
>   arm-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1:
>   /Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myApp-ddoknnyqnanytlcpbqpazmjjqbpx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libThree20Core.a:
>   No such file or directory
>   arm-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1:
>   /Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myApp-ddoknnyqnanytlcpbqpazmjjqbpx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libThree20Network.a:
>   No such file or directory
>   arm-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1:
>   /Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myApp-ddoknnyqnanytlcpbqpazmjjqbpx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libThree20Style.a:
>   No such file or directory
>   arm-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1:
>   /Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myApp-ddoknnyqnanytlcpbqpazmjjqbpx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libThree20UI.a:
>   No such file or directory
>   arm-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1:
>   /Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myApp-ddoknnyqnanytlcpbqpazmjjqbpx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libThree20UICommon.a:
>   No such file or directory
>   arm-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1:
>   /Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myApp-ddoknnyqnanytlcpbqpazmjjqbpx/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libThree20UINavigator.a:
>   No such file or directory Command
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2
>   failed with exit code 1

Thanks.

PS: I tried cleaning up the solution and also verified Library Search path is the same as another machine where it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have sorted this out. The situation was littel bit weird. The three20 libraries base SDK was setup to iphonesimulator and hence, it was generating *.a files for simulator path ..../Debug-iphonesimulator but my project was trying to look them on .../Debug-iphoneos path. The three20 library wasn't allowing me to build for iPhone unless I had removed iphonesimulator from supported platform and changed base SDK to iphones. Rebuild all three20 projects individually and then it worked fine!!

Comment: How did you removed the iphonesimulator from supported platform

Comment: what you mean? Just double click supported platform and remove simulator!

Comment: Hay I got it,  finally I fixed by removing armv7s from supported architecture and included the IOS5.1 sdk and compiled.  Thanks for helping me

Answer (score 0):

If cleaning the target in Xcode didn't work, try just trashing the build directory that's in your DerivedData folder for that app.